# Bootstrap popover

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть всплывающее окно(bootstrap), в title номер телефона, в контентной части иконки-ссылки на соцсети(Font Avesome).

Как изменить ширину окна, чтоб содержимое в title и в content помещалось в одну строку без переноса и отцентровывалось?

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right menu">
    <a href="#" class="btn active">регистрация</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn active">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> вход
    </a>

    <a class="btn active" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover"
        title="(XXX)-XXX-XX-XX"
        data-content="<div class='container-fluid'>
        <a href='http://vk.com/'>
        <span class='fa-stack fa-2x'>
        <i class='fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x' style='color: #adadad'></i>
        <i class='fa fa-vk fa-stack-1x' aria-hidden='true' style='color: blue;'></i>
        </span>
        </a>

        <a href='https://ok.ru/'>
        <span class='fa-stack fa-2x'>
        <i class='fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x'
            style='color: #adadad'></i>
        <i class='fa fa-odnoklassniki fa-stack-1x' aria-hidden='true'
            style='color: orangered;'></i>
        </span></a></div>"
    data-delay="180">контакты</a>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавь код в jsfiddle чтоб наглядно видеть почему так происходит

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос скрипт, который используете для поповера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз у вас на сайте код работает, то вы используете яваскрипт, который не добавили в свой вопрос. Судя по картинке, в вашем скрипте уже заданы параметры `html : true` и `placement : 'bottom'`.

Попробуйте прописать стили для поповера (как [соседнего](https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent) к вызывающей его ссылке):

1. запрещаем перенос на следующей строку;
2. центрируем содержимое строки;
3. после 1. и 2. правый край уходит за пределы экрана, надо его оттуда вытащить.

```js
$('#btn-contacts').popover({
  html : true,
  placement : 'bottom'
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

#btn-contacts + .popover>.popover-content,
#btn-contacts + .popover>.popover-title {
  white-space: nowrap;  /* 1. */
  text-align: center;   /* 2. */
}
#btn-contacts + .popover {
  right: 0;             /* 3. */
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right menu">
  <a href="#" class="btn active">регистрация</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn active">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> вход
  </a>

  <a id="btn-contacts" class="btn active" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" 
     title="(XXX)-XXX-XX-XX"
     data-content="<a href='http://vk.com/'>
                   <span class='fa-stack fa-2x'>
                   <i class='fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x' style='color: #adadad'></i>
                   <i class='fa fa-vk fa-stack-1x' aria-hidden='true' style='color: blue;'></i>
                   </span>
                   </a>

                   <a href='https://ok.ru/'>
                   <span class='fa-stack fa-2x'>
                   <i class='fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x'
                   style='color: #adadad'></i>
                   <i class='fa fa-odnoklassniki fa-stack-1x' aria-hidden='true'
                   style='color: orangered;'></i>
                   </span></a>"
     data-delay="180">контакты</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```